# Spring Boot Test, Cucumber, Senenity, Jersey - Correct set up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-serenity

What is the correct set up for Spring Boot Testing using CucumberSerenity?

The rest end point is not accessible and returning null.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class,
        loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class UserSteps {
    @Before
    public void configurePorts() {
        RestAssured.rootPath = "http://localhost";
        RestAssured.port = 8080;
        RestAssured.basePath = "/";
    }

    @Given("^a user$")
    public void a_user() throws Throwable {
        Response response = rest().given().get("/users"); //this returning null
    }
}


@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features/users")
public class Users {
}
```

Comment: what happens if you connect to the rest endpoint with curl or postman?

Comment: it is not accessible (no tomcat in the curl/postman response)

Comment: Sounds like your server under tests isn't running.

Comment: Yes, it is not running. The AppConfig.class is the one annotated with  SpringBootApplication